Menger and Scheepers subsets of $\mathbb R$
$\Omega$: The collection of all $\omega$-covers of a space $X$. An open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is said to be $\omega$-cover if $X\notin\mathcal U$ and for each finite $F\subseteq X$ there exists a $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $F\subseteq U$.
$\Gamma$: The collection of all $\gamma$-covers of a space $X$. An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is said to be $\gamma$-cover if $\mathcal{U}$ is infinite and each member of $X$ does not belong to at most finitely many members of $\mathcal{U}$.

A space $X$ is said to have the Menger property if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ covers $X$.

A space $X$ is said to have the Scheepers property if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}\in\Omega$ or $\cup\mathcal V_n=X$ for some $n$.

A space $X$ is said to have the Hurewicz property if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(\mathcal{V}_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}\in\Gamma$ or $\cup\mathcal V_n=X$ for some $n$.


Clearly Hurewicz $\Rightarrow$ Scheepers $\Rightarrow$ Menger.
In Finite powers and products of Menger sets and Scales, fields, and a problem of Hurewicz, we can find:

a set of reals which is Menger but not Scheepers;

a set of reals which is Scheepers but not Hurewicz.


So my questions are that:

Does there exist a set $Y \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $Y\cup \mathbb Q$ is Menger but not Scheepers?

Does there exist a set $Y \subseteq \mathbb R$ such that $Y\cup \mathbb Q$ is Scheepers but not Hurewicz?


Any comments and suggestions to the above problems will be a great help for me.

I believe that the sets in the paper that you cite (subsets of the Cantor space that contain the set of eventually 0 elements) are homeomorphic to sets of reals that contain the rational numbers, by a homeomorphism carrying the mentioned dense set to the rational numbers.
So, the answer should be positive, under the same hypotheses as in the papers that you cite.
